# Count () not working properly Mysql PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql

I have created one procedure which take 2 parameter and it check the count.
But when I pass `""` blank value  It still return 1 count.
Did not get it why it is working like this.
Thanks for the help below is my procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`dadclient`@`123.63.249.169` PROCEDURE `checkInOut`(IN grid varchar(50),OUT count INT)
begin 

select count(GRIDID) into count  from GRIDID where GRIDID=grid;
select count;

END
```

when I call

```
 checkInOut("",@aaa);
             select @aaa;
```

When I call this,it return me 1 which is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I pass "" blank value It still return 1 count.

Because when you say it is blank by providing an empty string it is a value. Empty string is also treated as a value in database and hence you get count as 1

The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) says:

> **COUNT(expr)**
>
> Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows
>   retrieved by a SELECT statement. The result is a BIGINT value.

So if you want the `count` to return **0** then instead of making the string as empty `""` you need to make the value as `NULL`.

Comment: But I dont have any value in database as " " So the count should be 0

Answer (score 0):

Yo mate, try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    DEFINER=`dadclient`@`123.63.249.169`
    PROCEDURE `checkInOut`(
        IN `grid` VARCHAR(50),
        OUT `count` INT
    )
BEGIN
-- insert value into variable
    SET `count` = (
        select count(GRIDID)
        from GRIDID
        where GRIDID=grid;
    );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So in your application, e.g. php you can `CALL checkInOut($input, $output);`. No need for the final `SELECT...` part in your initial code, afaik, because you already declared `count` as an `OUT` in the procedure `parameter`

**Note:**

- Is the name `GRIDID` the name of your table? because as I see, you also used it in your `WHERE` statement as a `key` filter
- Regarding your query, supposedly it is expected to `contain one row` of result. Kindly check that also mate